# monodroid 4.6 breakpoint not hit

Tags: android, debugging, for-loop, mono, xamarin.android

I'm using Mono for Android version 4.6.00049 with Visual Studio. I am debugging on a USB-attached Google Nexus 7.

I was able to break into the app being debugged. After installing the latest Mono for Android, debugging seems to have become unstable.

At first I wasn't able to debug my application at all: When starting the debugger, the application started on the device but Visual Studio did not enter into debug mode. After some seconds the app shut down on the device.

I followed an advice here on stack overflow to switch off "Use Fast Deployment" in the application project settings' "Mono Android Options" page.

Now Visual Studio enters debug mode and the app is not aborted on the device. **Yet no single break point is being hit.**

I read a couple of answers here on stack overflow all related to various settings on the "Mono Android Options" project property page. I realized that several settings lead to somme awkward "package tv.ouya.console.api does not exist" error when trying to rebuild the solution.

Please help. 
Thx
Christoph

Comment: Out of curiousity have you tried hitting a break point using Monodevelop to run the project? Just curious if this is systemic or if it relates to the mono VS integration.